# Property 'setTabChange' does not exist on type 'never'. (React hooks Typescript) using ref

Tags: reactjs, typescript

While calling child component function from parent component
`usingref(ref.current?.setTabChange())`.

> Property 'setTabChange' does not exist on type 'never'.

Using react typescript.

Parent Component :

```js
const ref = useRef();

<Tabs ref = {ref} selectedTabIndex={ data.isevaluation === "true" ? 2 : tabIndex !== -1 ? tabIndex : 0} onTabChange={() => {ref.current?.setTabChange()}} >
```

Child Component :

```js
const setTabChange = () => {
  setSelectedIndex(selectedTabIndex);
};

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
  return {
    setTabChange: setTabChange
  };
});
```

Comment: Can you include the definition of `ref`?

Comment: const ref = useRef(); ref definition

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As `useRef` is generic when it is used with TypeScript, you have to define the referenced element type like `const ref = useRef<Type>();`

So to fix this error you can define the `ref` like

```
const ref = useRef<any>();
```